# Android Bluetooth scan - how to know when it's finished?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using the `startScan` method of a [`BluetoothLeScanner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html) to collect information about available devices. However, I need to know when the scan has finished. There are no methods in [the callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback.html) that seem to indicate this.

How can I know when the scan has completed?

Comment: What would "completed" mean?  Bluetooth devices move in and out of range, turn off and on, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [stopScan()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#stopScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)) when you complete the functionality for scanning devices.
So it is more like the scan completes when you want it to, depending on whether you would want the scan to stop based on a time criteria or say after a few devices are found.

The decision point to do that would be [ScanCallback functions and results](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback.html).
[ScanResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult.html) can help.

Comment: I see - thanks. And is this a Bluetooth thing? Because I see that iOS also seemingly has no explicit notification when a scan completes.